# Virtual machine and cloud computing

Tags: cloud, virtualization

Can anyone explain the roles of virtual machines in cloud computing?
What kind of virtualization is required for cloud computing?
Can a cloud work without virtual machines?
And what are the possible interfaces to cloud services, how can a user access the cloud?

Comment: You are better off asking this on Serverfault.com

Comment: Agreed, not really a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

For some basic knowledge and understanding, read:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing

Furthermore, if you are interested in building a cloud, read up on Eucalyptus here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_%28computing%29

**

Virtual machines are simply a means to an end in cloud computing. If you have the resources you should be able to build a cloud running only physical machines. The virtual machines are simply there to split the resources of high-performance machines into "smaller" managed machines.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual machine is an operating system environment that is installed on software, which imitates dedicated hardware. The user has the same experience on a virtual machine as they would have on dedicated hardware. In a cloud environment, a user can provision virtual machines and specify resources without interacting with the underlying physical equipment. Some further reading: https://www.stratoscale.com/blog/hyperconvergence/virtual-machine-storage-what-does-vm-centric-storage-mean/